# Unknown class is created while creating angular tree, a separate div class is created after my angular tree code

Tags: html, css, angularjs

**This is my Angular tree code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html"
            class="ng-scope">
            <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
                    ng-if="node.nodes && node.nodes.length > 0" data-nodrag
                    ng-click="toggle(this)">
                    <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
                        ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed,'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed }">
                    </span>
                </a>
                {{node.title}}
                <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag
                    ng-click="remove(this)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag
                    ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes"
                ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node
                ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
                </li>
            </ol>
        </script>
        <div ui-tree>
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data" id="tree-root">
                <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node
                    ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>


    </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-green course-pannel">
        <div class="panel-heading">Section 1</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                        <label for="sec_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name<i>*</i></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 "
                            ng-class="{'has-error': courseForm.sec_name.$error.required && !courseForm.sec_name.$pristine , 'has-success' :courseForm.sec_name.$valid && courseForm.sec_name.$dirty }">
                            <input type="text" reg-ex-input reg-ex="^[a-z A-Z]+$"
                                ng-keypress="titleFunction()" name="sec_name"
                                class="form-control" ng-model="course.sec_name"
                                placeholder="Name" required maxlength="255" ng-maxlength="255"
                                tooltip="{{courseForm.sec_name.$error.required ? 'You can enter Maximum 255 letters ' : ''}}"
                                tooltip-trigger="focus" tooltip-placement="top"> <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success form-control-feedback"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                ng-show="courseForm.sec_name.$valid && courseForm.sec_name.$dirty"></span>
                            <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger form-control-feedback"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                ng-show="courseForm.sec_name.$invalid && !courseForm.sec_name.$pristine"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                        <label for="sec_summary" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Summary<i>*</i>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 "
                            ng-class="{'has-error': courseForm.sec_summary.$error.required && !courseForm.sec_summary.$pristine , 'has-success' :courseForm.sec_summary.$valid && courseForm.sec_summary.$dirty }">
                            <textarea class="form-control" reg-ex-input reg-ex="^[a-z A-Z0-9]+$"
                                name="usr_address1" rows="3" ng-keypress="addressFunction()"
                                maxlength="255" ng-maxlength="255" ng-model="user.usr_address1"
                                cols="40" title="You can enter less than 255 character" required
                                tooltip="{{userForm.usr_address1.$error.required ? 'You can enter Maximum 255 letters' : ''}}"
                                tooltip-trigger="focus" tooltip-placement="top">
                            </textarea> <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success form-control-feedback"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                ng-show="courseForm.sec_summary.$valid && courseForm.sec_summary.$dirty"></span>
                            <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger form-control-feedback"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                ng-show="courseForm.sec_summary.$invalid && !courseForm.sec_summary.$pristine"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
                        <button type="submit(user)" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

**Extra div class generated automatically**
<div class="tZMaGEFW" > </div>
```

Unknown class is created while creating angular tree, a separate div class is created after my angular tree code. This class I found by using inspect element. There are other codes are added to the div class which i am not able to show.